# FragmentStatePagerAdapter getItem not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter, pagertitlestrip

I have a `viewpager` with `PagerTitleStrip`.I adaptered my `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` successfully.

This is a my source:

```
public class CardsDetailsNewFragment extends MainFragment {


    private Card mCurrentCard;
    private View mView;
    private boolean mStatusAction;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private PagerTitleStrip mPagerTitleStrip;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_new_details, container, false);
        mCurrentCard = (Card) getData();

        Log.e("primary",CardsNewFragment.card_list.get(0).getPrimary()+"primary");
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) mView.findViewById(R.id.u_transaction_details_viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
        mPagerTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) mView.findViewById(R.id.u_transaction_details_header);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(CardsNewFragment.cardposition);



        return mView;
    }
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            TransactionDetailsFragment transactionDetailsFragment=new TransactionDetailsFragment();
            transactionDetailsFragment.setCard(CardsNewFragment.card_list.get(position));
            transactionDetailsFragment.setViewPagerPosition(position);
            syncTitles(position);
            return transactionDetailsFragment;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return CardsNewFragment.card_list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String title = CardsNewFragment.card_list.get(position).getName();
            SpannableString whiteSpannable = new SpannableString(title);
            whiteSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, title.length(), 0);
            return whiteSpannable;
        }
    }
    void syncTitles(int position) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < mPagerTitleStrip.getChildCount(); counter++) {
            if (mPagerTitleStrip.getChildAt(counter) instanceof TextView) {
                TextView textView = ((TextView) mPagerTitleStrip.getChildAt(counter));

                textView.setTextColor(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == position ? getResources().getColor(R.color.u_white) : getResources().getColor(R.color.u_color));
                textView.setTextSize(14);
            }
        }
    }
    class TransactionDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
        private Card card;
        private int possiton;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testlayout, container, false);


            printCardInfo(card,view,possiton);
            Log.e("card",card.getName()+"name is");
            final SwitchButton primaryCardSwitch = (SwitchButton) view.findViewById(R.id.u_cards_default);
            if(card.getPrimary()==1)
            {
                primaryCardSwitch.setChecked(true);
                primaryCardSwitch.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                primaryCardSwitch.setChecked(false);
                primaryCardSwitch.setEnabled(true);
            }


            return view;
        }

        public void setCard(Card card) {
            this.card = card;
        }
        public void setViewPagerPosition(int position)
        {
            this.possiton=position;
        }
    }
    private void printCardInfo( final Card card, View view,final int position) {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.u_card_number)).setText(card.getCardBrand() + " - " + card.getCardNumber());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.u_card_bank_title)).setText(card.getBankName());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.u_card_holder)).setText(card.getHolder());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.u_card_status)).setText(CardStatus.getByStatus(card.getStatus()).getStatusName());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.u_card_status)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(CardStatus.getByStatus(card.getStatus()).getColor()));


        mView.findViewById(R.id.u_cards_transfer).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                transfer(card);
                Log.e("position,",position +"position");
                Log.e("uploaddddddd", card + "get primary");
            }
        });

    }
    void transfer(final Card card) {
        removeOnDetach();
        mData = card;
        mainCallbacks.addFragment(TransferNewVersion.class);
    }


}
```

I have one problem: my `setViewPagerPositio`n method is not working perfect.when I call transfer `method(button click)`, my code must select card by position, but for example if I have 4 element in my `viewpager` and select first `items(Card)` in my log I can see second `Item (Card)`.
position +1

```
Log.e("uploaddddddd", card + "get primary");
```

I have no idea what is a wrong in my code: I have position problem in my option

Comment: could you explain your problem properly? it is difficult to understand what the problem is

Comment: i try to explain.I have  one button and 4 Cards (items)in my viewpager for example if i scrolled and click button when  my viewpager position is 2,in button click selected 3th position(3th positions Card) @user_user1